# How to redirect to another page without having access to .php file?

Tags: php, html

I have a html page in which I have complex form. For sending the data to my email I use mailer from the site at which I created my form. After completing and sending the data I see an error:

"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

But after sending the data I'd like to go to another page. I know how to move to another page when I create my own php file (header("Location: page.html")). Do you know how to implement it, when I don't have an access to php file?

Part of the code looks like this:

```
<FORM name="mlwebform" onSubmit="return checkForm(this)" method="POST" action="http://www.mouselabweb.org/mlwebmailer.php"><INPUT type=hidden name="procdata" value="">
```

I tried to add a hyperlink in submit button, but it doesn't work.

```
<a href = "ocena.html"><input style="height:50px; width: 100px; font-size:12pt;" type="submit" value="Dalej" onClick=timefunction('submit','submit','submit')></a>
```

Comment: The error tells you everything, it can't find the page you're sending the form data to, mlwebmailer.php.  If this is a file on another server you don't control, you can't redirect the user to anywhere else once they leave your site.  You can use an ajax call to send the form data without leaving your page and then upon success forward them to another page.

Comment: That's a good idea. I tried implement this:

Comment: <script>
    function create () {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://www.mouselabweb.org/mlwebmailer.php",    //the page containing php script
            type: "post",    //request type,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {registration: "success", name: "xyz", email: "abc@gmail.com"},
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result.abc);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

Comment: but the result is the same as before :/

Comment: Did you even visit https://www.mouselabweb.org/mlwebmailer.php ? its full of errors...

Comment: When I call this in html everything is okay. Going strait to this mailer you can see some errors, because it's refering to .js file. Anyway it sends me proper results and that's the most important thing